# Include graphics from the web

Tags: graphics

Is it possible to include a graphic file hosted on the web instead of hosted on my local folder?

For example, something like this:

```
\includegraphics{www.example.com/logo.pdf}
```

**ps:** of course, that url is fake.

Comment: This has come up in the past, e.g. [Can I use an image located on the web in a LaTeX document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5433/can-i-use-an-image-located-on-the-web-in-a-latex-document), [Creating a URL downloading command to be used with e.g. \includegraphics](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88430/creating-a-url-downloading-command-to-be-used-with-e-g-includegraphics) and other questions. See also the [`download` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/download) on CTAN.

Comment: Thanks. How did you find that post? I tried to look for.