# \input a .tex file from an url

Tags: texlive, urls, input

Is it possible to use `\input` with an url as parameter:

```
\input{https://mywebsite.com/mylatex.tex}
```

If not, is there any way to achieve this?
I am using the TeX Live distribution.

Comment: In general no, but there are tricks to get around this restriction. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5433/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88430/35864

Comment: See also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249567/69818): I gave an answer that contains a “working example”.